# Is Auto-sklearn available for apple silicon?

Tags: apple-m1, automl, auto-sklearn

I have my laptop to be the latest MBP with M1 chip. Weird errors popped out while I was trying to install the auto-sklearn package for my machine. I wonder is that package compatible with M1 chip or is there any method that I am able to get it installed on my machine?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error as you on a M1 MacBook Air and solved it by doing:

```
brew install swig
```

Answer (score 0):

`brew install swig` is indeed required like @pmadruga said. Here is the [official installation guide on MacOS](https://gist.github.com/simonprovost/051952533680026b67fa58c3552b8a7b?permalink_comment_id=4239572#gistcomment-4239572).